# How to loop over and add values to an array in Angular forms

Tags: angular, angularjs, forms, asp.net-web-api, angular-reactive-forms

HI so i'm trying to set up a basic attendance system using `ASP.NET` core web api as backend and `Angular` as front end i'll provide you the code and then explain the problem

```
<form [formGroup]="attendanceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <section class="form-part">
    <div class="row" id="form-part-row">
      <div class="col" id="form-part-heading-col">Mark <br> Attendance</div>
      <div class="col" id="form-part-date-col">
        <input type="date" formControlName="date" id="date-input"
        class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div *ngFor="let item of getclass">
    <section class="student-list" *ngFor="let student of item.students">
      <div class="row" id="student-list-row">
        <div class="col" id="student-list-name-col">{{student?.name}} - {{student?.rollNumber}}</div>
        <div class="col" id="student-list-mark-col">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-present" type="button" (click)="attendanceForm.patchValue({isPresent: true, studentId: student.id});">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-hand" (click)="onPresentClick(student.id)" [ngStyle]="{ borderBottom: studentsClicked[student.id] === true ? '3px solid #d2f9a7' : 'none' }"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-absent" type="button" (click)="attendanceForm.patchValue({isPresent: false, studentId: student.id});">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-hand-fist" (click)="onAbsentClick(student.id)" [ngStyle]="{ borderBottom: studentsClicked[student.id] === false ? '3px solid #d2f9a7' : 'none' }"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <section class="mark-button">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" id="submit-button-col">
        <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit">Mark Attendacne</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

So this is the form used to add attendace now the form initialization is

```
  this.attendanceForm = this.fb.group({
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      classid: [this.classId, Validators.required],
      studentId: ['', Validators.required],
      isPresent: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

and the method to add attendance

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.attendanceRecords = []; // clear the array
  
    if (this.attendanceForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
  
    this.getclass.forEach((cls) => {
      cls.students.forEach((student) => {
        const isPresent = this.attendanceForm.get(`isPresent`)?.value;
        const studentId = student.id;
        this.attendanceRecords.push({ studentId: studentId, isPresent: isPresent });
      });
    });
  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.attendanceRecords));
  
    this.service.addAttendance(this.classId, this.attendanceForm.get('date')?.value, this.attendanceRecords).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Attendance added successfully.');
      console.log(this.attendanceRecords);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Now the problem is that lets say i have two students i select present for the first student and absent for the second student now if i add the attendance or other words call the submit method it adds false or absent for both of the student as the value of `isPresent` the value that is passed latter is added as the value for `isPresent` but i want that for what student what value is passed it should be kept any idea how i can solve this problem.

i want that for what student whaat value is passed it should be kept any idea how i can solve this problem any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: change angular form to an formArray with for ex:-[userId1: {name:userName1, age:userAge1}, userId2:{name:userName2, age:userAge2}]

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of students. You cannot bind this collection to a single control in your form group. What you need is [FormArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms). To build your form group, with GroupArray in it, you may use something like this:

```
    this.attendanceForm = fb.group({
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      classid: [this.classId, Validators.required],
      students: fb.array(this.getClass.map(c => {
        return fb.group({
          studentId: [c.studentId, Validators.required],
          isPresent: [c.isPresent, Validators.required],
        });
      })),
    });
```

In your html file you should bind the form like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="attendanceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <section class="form-part">
    <input type="date" formControlName="date" id="date-input" class="form-control" />
  </section>
  <!-- In *ngFor container you should set formArrayName! -->
  <div [formArrayName]="'students'" *ngFor="let student of getClass; let i = index">
    <div class="col" id="student-list-name-col">
      {{ student?.name }} - {{ student?.rollNumber }}
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="setPresent(i, true)">Present</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="setPresent(i, false)">Absent</button>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit">Mark Attendacne</button>
</form>
```

To change the value of a given student in the students array under your form group you can use code like this:

```
  public setPresent = (studentIndex: number, present: boolean): void => {
    // Get the students form array
    const studentsFormArray: FormArray = this.attendanceForm.controls['students'] as FormArray;

    // use `at` to get the student control group at index in the form array
    const studentControlGroup: FormGroup = studentsFormArray.at(studentIndex) as FormGroup;

    // get `isPresent` control from the form group
    const isPresentControl = studentControlGroup.controls['isPresent']

    // patch the value
    isPresentControl.patchValue(present);
  };
```